# How do you set the Android emulator to stay on the right side in Android Studio?

Tags: android, preview

I'm new to Android development world. I installed the Android Studio with a sample. When I imported my school project, the emulator that was on the right side went away. How do I bring it back, and keep it there?

This is how I would like to have my Android studio look ( please view image ):

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio&client=firefox-a&hs=Blp&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=KOgQU5KmKOO52QW2l4DwAg&ved=0CAsQ_AUoAw&biw=1600&bih=736#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=-oMUoh5tH67u4M%253A%3BOIjZ8Oq8VPtePM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.omgchrome.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F05%252Fandroid-studio.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.omgchrome.com%252Fthoughts-from-google-io-2013%252F%3B620%3B341

Thank you very much,
Stefanely

Answer (score 0):

That's not the android emulator, it's just the layout editor.

You can make it visible with the "preview" option on the right side while editing an xml layout.